# How do I update a Clickhouse table to be able to sample from it?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to sample rows from a clickhouse table.
Below you can find the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE trades
(
    `id` UInt32,
    `ticker_id` UUID,
    `epoch` DateTime,
    `nanoseconds` UInt32,
    `amount` Float64,
    `cost` Float64,
    `price` Float64,
    `side` UInt8
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY (ticker_id, toStartOfInterval(epoch, toIntervalHour(1)))
ORDER BY (ticker_id, epoch)

SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

I want to sample 10000 rows from the table

```
SELECT * FROM trades SAMPLE 10000 ;
```

But when I'm trying to run the query above I'm getting the following error:

`DB::Exception: Illegal SAMPLE: table doesn't support sampling`

I want to `ALTER` the table in order to be able to sample from it, but at the same time I want to make sure that I won't corrupt the data while altering the table.
The table has about 1 billion rows.

What would be a good way to ALTER the table while making sure the data won't get corrupted?

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/sampling-example/

Comment: you have only one option: create a new table and insert data from the old

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
ALTER TABLE trades MODIFY SAMPLE BY toUnixTimestamp(toIntervalHour(epoch));
```